# How do I define an optional parameter in powershell that takes no value? (e.g. get-object -verbose)

Tags: powershell

I need to expose debug or verbose data in a powershell script.  How can I define a function that allows the user to either run with `get-object` or `get-object -verbose`?

Comment: Are you asking how to generally implement a switch-type parameter of which `-Verbose` is an _example_, or are you asking how to make your script support verbose output that is controlled via the common `-Verbose` (switch) parameter? Please clarify by updating your question directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the `CmdletBinding` attribute to your function:

```
function Get-Object
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    PARAM()

    Write-Verbose "You'll only see this with -Verbose"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To **NOT** use `-verbose` but a switch:

```
function get-object{
   param (
     [switch]$gassy
   )
   "switch gassy is {0}" -f $gassy
}
```

---

```
> get-object
switch gassy is False
> get-object -gassy
switch gassy is True
```

---

See `Get-Help about_commonparameters`

> -Verbose[:{$true | $false}]
>          Alias: vb

```
   Displays detailed information about the operation performed by the
   command. This information resembles the information in a trace or in
   a transaction log. This parameter works only when the command generates
   a verbose message. For example, this parameter works when a command
   contains the Write-Verbose cmdlet.

   The Verbose parameter overrides the value of the $VerbosePreference
   variable for the current command. Because the default value of the
   $VerbosePreference variable is SilentlyContinue, verbose messages
   are not displayed by default.

   Valid values:

       $true (-Verbose:$true) has the same effect as -Verbose.

       $false (-Verbose:$false) suppresses the display of verbose
       messages. Use this parameter when the value of $VerbosePreference
       is not SilentlyContinue (the default).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `param` function. In this case I've defined a variable called `$obj` which is a string and is bound to a command-line parameter called "Get-Object".

```
param (
    [string]$obj = Get-Object 
)

If($obj)
{
    "Do Something"
}
else
{
    "Do Something Else"
}
```